# Add elements of an array as a[0],a[1]+a[2],a[3]+a[4]+a[5],a[6]+a[7]+a[8]+a[9]...and so on

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of integers. Now i want to get the sum of the elements of array as shown below:

`a[0]`,`a[1]+a[2]`,`a[3]+a[4]+a[5]`,`a[6]+a[7]+a[8]+a[9]`

This is the logic i am trying to use but it does not work well :

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.lenght;i++){
    int temp = 0;
    for(int j=i;j=i+1;j++){
        temp += arr[i];
    }
    println("Now the sum is %d",temp);
 }
```

Can any one say what should i do ?

Comment: What is the j used for ?

Comment: sorry i edited question..that was one silly typing

Comment: check this line: `for(int j=i;j=i+1;j++){` it will itterate only once for every i, j (Oops; edit: it won't iterate at all.)

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to store the values of each partial sum somewhere or just accumulate?

Comment: So it the number of items in each sum always increasing by 1? What happens if there isn't enough items left in the array for the last sum?

Comment: @Stefan may be i should try  for(int j=i;j<=2i;j++){....

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves no i just want to print the value for now

Comment: @TheDark thats the condition there???i am trying to get help on it too

Comment: Looks like java code with some typos.

Comment: yesterday i posted with Java tag..and delete it..thought its about logic so i posted again with C tag..and i got help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have just 10 array alements do it directly:

```
int sum1 = a[0];
int sum2 = a[1] + a[2];
...
```

If you are after the general principle you need this:

```
int start = 0;
int len = 1;

while(start + len < array_length)
{
    int sum = calc_sum(start, len);
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    start += len;
    len++;
}
```

With this helper function:

```
int calc_sum(int start, int len)
{
     int sum = 0;
     for(int i = start; i < start + len; i++) 
        sum += a[i];
     return sum;
}
```

Comment: yeah this iswhat i am looking for :)